# Eclipse CDT doesn't run the program

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have written a small piece of code in C++(gui/wxWidgets) . It compiles/ links without any errors and produces an executable that when launched from command line opens the desired 'Hello World!' window, but when tried from within eclipse (menu, toolbar or ctrl-F11), it doesn't run. A quick error dialog appears/disappears before it can be read. After many runs I could make out that of the two msgs it displays, one reads something like "Looking for executables...". Apparently eclipse is unable to get to the executable in the Debug folder.

I tried a console application which runs without any issue from within eclipse as well.

My installation is indigo on Ubuntu 12.04.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.

There was no Launch Configuration in Project Properties -> Run/Debug Settings.
Added one with defaults and it worked.